# Add Firebase child on dashboard

Tags: firebase

Here is the picture of how it looks like:
http://gyazo.com/f9ef3abb6a09c9632dc0445e8a405be2.
And this is how it looks like when i hover over a child already containing children http://gyazo.com/4d855b235f54b933f7c7103a919827ba.
As you can see I'm wondering if there is a problem for me or if Firebase has decided that you can't create new children to a child from the dashboard?

Comment: Answer below, this is just commentary: please consider using a different image hosting service or just uploading the images into StackOverflow directly. Requiring the people who might be able to answer your question to click to an external site to see your screenshots is not the best way to trigger their helpfulness.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, due to Stackoverflow's settings I can not upload images until I have gained 10 reputation on my account.

Comment: I upvoted your question, as long as you promise to change the images once you reach the necessary reputation. :-p (1 point left to go)

Comment: Of course, I will. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firebase a node can *either* have a value *or* it can have children. So if you hover over the `wronganswer1` and `wronganswer2` nodes, you cannot add a child node, since they both already have a value.

If you remove the `wronganswer1` node *and* value, and then add the node again, you will see that you get the option to add children under it.